# How to split strings with special characters without removing those characters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, special-characters

I'm writing this function which needs to return an abbreviated version of a `str`. The return `str` must contain the first letter, number of characters removed and the, last letter;it must be abbreviated per word and not by sentence, then after that I need to join every word again with the same format including the special-characters. I tried using the `re.findall()` method but it automatically removes the special-characters so I can't use `" ".join()` because it will leave out the special-characters.

Here's my code:

```
import re
def abbreviate(wrd):
    return " ".join([i if len(i) < 4 else i[0] + str(len(i[1:-1])) + i[-1] for i in re.findall(r"[\w']+", wrd)]) 

print(abbreviate("elephant-rides are really fun!"))
```

The output would be:

```
e6t r3s are r4y fun
```

But the output should be:

```
e6t-r3s are r4y fun!
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for `str.join`. Might as well take full advantage of what the `re` module has to offer.

`re.sub` accepts a string or a callable object (like a function or lambda), which takes the current match as an input and must return a string with which to replace the current match.

```
import re

pattern = "\\b[a-z]([a-z]{2,})[a-z]\\b"
string = "elephant-rides are really fun!"

def replace(match):
    return f"{match.group(0)[0]}{len(match.group(1))}{match.group(0)[-1]}"

abbreviated = re.sub(pattern, replace, string)

print(abbreviated)
```

Output:

```
e6t-r3s are r4y fun!
>>>
```

Maybe someone else can improve upon this answer with a cuter pattern, or any other suggestions. The way the pattern is written now, it assumes that you're only dealing with lowercase letters, so that's something to keep in mind - but it should be pretty straightforward to modify it to suit your needs. I'm not really a fan of the repetition of `[a-z]`, but that's just the quickest way I could think of for capturing the "inner" characters of a word in a separate capturing group. You may also want to consider what should happen with words/contractions like `"don't"` or `"shouldn't"`.

Comment: I want to improve my code without changing it too much. But thank you, I appreciate your answer and I will also try this method.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for viewing my question. After a few more searches, trial, and error I finally found a way to execute my code properly without changing it too much. I simply substituted `re.findall(r"[\w']+", wrd)` with `re.split(r'([\W\d\_])', wrd)` and also removed the `whitespace` in `"".join()` for they were simply not needed anymore.

```
    import re
    def abbreviate(wrd):
        return "".join([i if len(i) < 4 else i[0] + str(len(i[1:-1])) + i[-1] for i in re.split(r'([\W\d\_])', wrd)])

     print(abbreviate("elephant-rides are not fun!"))
```

Output:

```
     e6t-r3s are not fun!
```